# Unreal engine 4 - UI blury

Tags: windows, gui, user-interface, development

I have posted this on the dev stackexchange and have been redirected here. My problem is as follows:

My unreal engine UI does not look sharp and is blurred on my 1080p monitor. Subsequently, the viewport is slightly blurry and edges are jagged . I have changed the setting of the viewport to cinematic yet this still persists?

I have been suggested to post here

I have two images available where the first is mine and as you can see, the image is slightly blurred and text on the left-hand side is not sharp.

The second image is from a YOUTUBE video which has been compressed(by youtube) yet it still looks better?

[The images on my original post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136086/unreal-engine-4-ui-blury?noredirect=1#comment238710_136086)

How can I make the UI more crisp and prevent the blurring?

anyone?

Comment: Are you using Windows 10?

Comment: @dark_st3alth  yes I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 on some systems will by default, use a display scaling of 125%.

[image: Windows 10 Scaling at 125%]

Many older programs used hard coded font sizes, and images of a fixed resolution. Because of the 'abnormal' scaling, dialog boxes for installations, and others will appear blurry.

Using the Control Panel, you can set the sizing back to 100%, which is what many programs expect.

[image: Windows 10 Scaling at 100%]